# Add subscriber to a Mailchimp group / update form answers via web request

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, mailchimp

I've a two-step newsletter signup form on a static webpage, which starts with a simple text field on the landing page with the email text field and a button.

I make a JSONP request to the POST endpoint of my custom Mailchimp form to subscribe a user.

When the user hits signup, I already want to fire the request to make sure that's done right way, even if the user decides to not give me any further information, but it also open a popup to prompt for a few more details about their interests, which I would like to organize as groups in Mailchimp. If I just try to re-subscribe the email address, this fails with the following error:

> [xxx@yyy] is already subscribed to list [zzz]

So this approach doesn't seem to be working. What else can I do to achieve this user experience, without having to delay the request and potentially missing signups.

Answer (score 0):

The request on the second form with additional information should be PATCH/PUT to update the user that you create

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP Curl with "PATCH" method. An example:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<LIST_ID>/members/<MEMBER_ID (= MD5 of subscriber's e-mail)>';

$data = ['merge_fields' => ['FNAME' => $name]]; // If you want to add his/her name

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Authorization: Basic <YOUR_API_KEY>', 'Content-Type: application/json'],
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
]);
curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $httpcode;
```

Mailchimp API Reference: https://mailchimp.com/developer/api